# Will changing geographic target country in Google Search Console to "unlisted" cause search traffic from my previous target country to decrease?

Tags: seo, geotargeting

My website is currently set to target country to India in search console settings. Currently my 95% organic traffic is from India and rest of it is mainly from US. (This info is from WP stats in dashboard. I don't have Google Analytics due to basic plan limitations).

Now I also want to write some content targeting US region. Search console suggests to change the target location to "Unlisted" if I want to target multiple countries.

Will my organic traffic of India go down if I change target location to "Unlisted"? The language will remain same: English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact/particular answer for this. With International Targeting, the users are shown results based on the domain set preferably for that region.

In your case, you have set the International Targeting to India and are looking to change it to unlisted, the ranking affect might or might not vary depending on the work done. Below is a summary of your ranking estimates based on the keywords your website ranks for:

> Keyword Type: "Generic Keyword"

`example: pmp training`

In this case, if Google has been ranking you, changing the International Targeting to unlisted, might affect your rankings.

**For India:** Ranking changes will be minimal.

**For other countries:** you cannot expect the same rankings.

> Keyword Type: "Generic Keyword" + "Location"

`example: pmp training in delhi`

In this case, if Google has been ranking you, changing the International Targeting to unlisted will not affect your ranking, as you have been ranking for the exact region and Google does not have to validate or consider additional factors.

Comment: let say my site ranks for "iphone X payment options" with post having Amazon.in(India) affiliate links. Now if I write post for, let say, 'Galaxy S10 payment option" with Amazon.com links for US traffic. What will happen to my first post after changing targeting to unlisted?

Comment: [1] For "iphone x payment options" it is highly unlikely that your rankings in India are affected by the international targeting change. For "Galaxy S10 payment option" you will gain rankings usually. About your affiliate links, Google does not rank your page based on .com or .in links in it.

Comment: [2] If you are just trying to do the targeting based on country-affiliate links, why don't you create a subdomain or sub-folder say " us.example.com" or " example.com/us/galaxy_s10" and submit that property for international targeting in US? (If you are focusing on all countries or want to put single effort towards ranking, general settings and international targeting to unlisted will help.)

Comment: thanks for the ideas. I have decided to go with your second advice. created us.<mysite>.com. Just one more thing to ask. Shall I create 10 or more post without publishing it and publish it altogether and get it indexed OR  publish one post at time?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd plan content marketing calendar for 10 posts and release one at a time to gain attention from the customers as well as give reasonable time for indexing.